# Run powershell script within powershell script (Intune related)

Tags: powershell, intune

This is Intune related but could probably apply outside the scope of Intune as well.

I wrote a PowerShell script that downloads a folder from an Azure blob storage and extracts the content. Within the extracted folder is another PowerShell script that I want to run.

The PowerShell script is deployed in Intune and runs successfully all the way up to the point where the second PowerShell script runs. From the log, it's running into a permission issue.

Scripts deployed through Intune are ran as administrator/system and don't require any local policy change to allow the execution of PowerShell scripts on the device. However on the device, the user account is only a standard user so they don't have permissions to execute PowerShell scripts. In the first script, I've included the "Set-ExclusionPolicy Bypass" command already.

I need to be able to deploy the script from Intune to the local device and essential run another script as the local user (non administrator account). I thought maybe I needed the local user to be included in the local administrators group to be able to run the second script but that did not work either.

Also read somewhere that PowerShell can run PowerShell scripts from other PowerShell scripts directly. The only time you need Start-Process for that is when you want to run the called script with elevated privileges (which isn't necessary here, since your parent script is already running elevated).

^^^Is this my issue? My script does include "Start-Process" to run the next powershell script.

Script below for reference.

```
New-Item -Path "C:\IT Drivers" -ItemType Directory ; 
Invoke-WebRequest - Uri 'https://xyz.zip' -OutFile "C:\xyz.zip" ; 
Expand-Archive -Path "C:\xyz.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\";
Set-ExclusionPolicy Bypass ; 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 ; 
Start-Process powershell "C:\xyz.ps1"
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Okay think I got it now. And if it's not clear I'm attempting to run multiple commands back to back.

Comment: Thanks. You probably meant `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, not `Set-ExclusionPolicy`, and you shouldn't set it  to `Bypass` _persistently_, only on a _per-process_ basis, which means passing `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the `powershell.exe` call, before the script path (before which  you should place `-File`). If you need `Start-Process` in order to run the script _as a different user_, you'll need to provide that user's credentials via `-Credential`. Also note that the invocation (which will happen in a _new window_ (which you could hide)) will be _asynchronous_ by default, unless you add `-Wait`.

Comment: If you simply want to run the script from the current script (in the same window, as the same user, synchronously), replace the `Start-Process` call with `& "C:\xyz.ps1"` - then you also don't have to worry about execution policies.

Comment: Also, when you use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` (without `-Scope Process`), the resulting _persistent_ change only takes effect in _future_ sessions.

Comment: So I'm NOT trying to run the script as a different user. The script being deployed through Intune is running as system in a 64-bit PowerShell Host which I want/need the other script to run as too. 

I want to run the script from the current script as you mentioned. 

So in that case would my last two lines of code look like this?

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 ; & "C:\xyz.ps1"

Comment: Yes (and remove the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call; what is the `Start-Sleep` for? `Expand-Archive` is synchronous, so when it returns everything's unpacked already).

Comment: My thought process for the Start-Sleep is to wait 30 seconds before executing the next powershell script because the previous commands downloads and extracts the zip folder and I wanted to ensure those files are present first before executing the last script. If that's unnecessary from your opinion, I can try it without it.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The last script doesn't run.

I get this error message," The term 'C:\xyz.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program."

What does the "&" do that you had me include?

Comment: This implies that no such script (`C:\xyz.ps1`) exists. `&` is PowerShell's [call operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) and needed for _syntactic_ reasons when you're trying to invoke a script with a path that is either _quoted_ and/or contains _variable references_. Since your path doesn't strictly need quoting, `C:\xyz.ps1` by itself would work too (but obviously only if the path is correct).